# Which new is execute first -- in constructor or out?

Tags: java, constructor

If I define a class like following:

```
public class myClass {
    private x = new anotherClass();
    private y;

    public myClass() {
        y = new anotherClass();
    } 
}
```

which variable will get instance earlier? x or y?

And, is it unrecommended to assign a variable outside the constructor?

Comment: `x` of course, because if you do a null check for `x` you'll see that it's not null in the constructor.

Comment: Your sentence is true, but your reasoning makes no sense for me. Doing the check means that in this particular case `x` wasn't null. It could be because of the variable being declared before the constructor or whatever.... reading the JLS is the only way to know for sure.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The order of execution is:

- Superclass constructor (or chained constructor to the same class)
- Instance variable initializers (the expression assigning to `x` in your code)
- Constructor body (the statement assigning to `y` in your code)

[Section 12.5 of the Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/execution.html#44670) contains the details.

Whether you assign the variable in the constructor or not is up to you - I quite like a rule of thumb whereby if the initial value doesn't depend on any constructor parameters, and will *always* be the same for *all* constructors, use a variable initializer. Otherwise, assign it in a constructor.

Comment: I don't understand. If superclass's constructor executes first, why can we call it in subclass's constructor by "super()"?

Comment: whether you explicitly call the super class constructor or not, it is always called as the first method of the sub class's constructor. So yes, the sub class gets called first, but the super class's finishs first.

Comment: @Lai: The fact that it's expressed as the first statement in a constructor body is somewhat misleading. I prefer the C# way, where it's specified *before* the constructor body - that makes it clearer what's going on (although the ordering is slightly different there anyway). You can't just execute the superclass constructor at any time, either - it *has* to be the first statement in the body.

Comment: So explicitly calling super() is totally unnecessary?

Comment: @Lai Yu-Hsuan - calling super() is completely unnecessary unless you need to call a super constructor with arguments.

Comment: Yes, just calling `super()` without any args makes no sense since it gets done anyway. Some people do it for "clarity" but in fact it's just polluting the code.

Comment: If I call the sub's constructor with (args), will super(args) be called anyway? or I should explicitly call it?

Comment: @Lai: No, unless you specify a superclass constructor it will always try to invoke a *parameterless* one. The constructor arguments aren't passed up automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Your variables in your code has **no** types, but `x` is instantiated first before the constructor is called. (Do a null check for `x` on constructor to find out).

As for recommendation, it's up to you. One thing, e.g. in JavaBeans, since I usually don't write a default public constructor (with no arguments), I tend to initialize some fields on declaration (if they are needed to be not null). Otherwise, I instantiate them on constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you test, instead of just getting an answer from someone else:

Make the constructor of `anotherClass` print the string passed through.

```
public class myClass {
    private anotherClass x = new anotherClass("outside constructor");
    private anotherClass y;

    public myClass() {
        y = new anotherClass("inside constructor");
    } 
}
```

And then you can tell us!

Comment: Testing will tell you what it does in one particular situation... but it doesn't guarantee that the behaviour is well-defined, or what will happen in other situations. I prefer to check the specification for such things.

Comment: @Jon, point taken, although my first port of call (a view which I was trying to share) is to be self-sufficient and try and figure out what happens by myself.

Comment: @davin: Yes, that's reasonable. A mixture of testing/exploration and spec consultation often works well.

Comment: I agree with @Jon - learning by reading-the-textbook is more reliable than learning-by-random-experiments.  The trouble with trying to figure things out yourself is that you don't necessarily know the right experiments to perform.

Comment: @Stephen, more reliable, definitely! But you tell a beginner just getting the basics of OO and programming to read the language spec and see how much they get out of it - not everyone is ready to jump into the deep end. I also don't see what is random about this. There is a particular case and it is being tested, no random distribution of any kind is being discussed. I'm not advocating this as a way to become proficient in a language, I'm advocating it as an excellent first step to see what happens, and get an idea of how the language (yes, a specific implementation) behaves

Comment: @Davin - normally, I'd recommend they look at a text book.  See my answer above.  FWIW - specific Java implementations behave pretty much the same, and you should be aiming to write your code to *avoid* cases where they don't.  You won't learn how to do that by trial and error.